# Session duration still not increased even when GC Max lifetime and Session set cookie param value increased by 3 hours

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, garbage-collection, session-cookies

`ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 10800); session_set_cookie_params(10800);`

Have been used to increase the session time.

The cookie expires max age as seen in application tab also increased in value, but still the session never lasts for 3 hours.

It expires like it used to expire earlier like 24 minutes. Please can anyone tell me about the cause and the fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',10800);
session_set_cookie_params(10800);
```

Are these the first statements of your script? It should be! Specifically before `session_start();` or any other header-sending statement (example: `echo`)!

If you're using other PHP scripts that do not change the `session.gc_maxlifetime` ini value to 10800 too during these sessions time, these script could potentially garbage collect the sessions before the 3 hours you desire.

Two solutions:

1.You change the `session.gc_maxlifetime` ini value globally in your `php.ini` file

2.Every script you run should also change the `session.gc_maxlifetime` ini value to 10800.

Comment: Yes sir, These are the first two lines of the script.  All scripts run these two lines.
Chrome session cookie has the correct expire time of 3 hours but session runs out anytime around 30 minutes.

Comment: @BestSolutionsfinder i would suggest trying with `session.gc_maxlifetime` ini value set to 10800 in your php.ini file first and see the result, before continuing the troubleshooting!